# Why destroy scope not working after calling $scope.destroy()

Tags: angularjs

My application complex from tabs that every one of them is a different scope. When I close a tab I fired event of 'Close_Tab' and all the controllers have

```
$rootScope.$on('Close_Tab', function (event, data)
```

that should catch this event.

When I said all the controllers I mean all the open tabs. 
The problem is that if I close tab and I write:

```
element.remove() // remove the tab from the DOM.
$scope.destroy()
```

the scope not removed!! 
When I debug the application I saw that the closed tab still get the event.

Any one has some idea?

Comment: I have gave answer below. if you are getting answer then please tick right sign. @tehila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What solved this was to call deregister() function in the $on event.
because $on event return the deregister function of the event and all what we need to do is to call that function.

Answer (score 0):

`$rootScope.$on()` returns a function that will deregister the listener.

That function should be invoked when the directive's scope is destroyed.

```
// add listener and hold on to deregister function
var deregister = $rootScope.$on('eventName', function(event) {
     // your best code
});


// clean up listener when directive's scope is destroyed

$scope.$on('$destroy', deregister);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.. Your answer sound good but I made the scope destroy in the $on event and then I tried to write this row   $scope.$on('$destroy', deregister); in that event but it's not working. So where should I destroy the event?

Answer (score 0):

Scope event listeners should be registered with $scope, not $rootScope. Then they will be automatically removed when the scope is destroyed:

```
̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶o̶n̶(̶'̶C̶l̶o̶s̶e̶_̶T̶a̶b̶'̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶,̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶

$scope.$on('Close_Tab', function (event, data)
```

---

> The problem is that the $emit is in a $rootscope level, so the $scope didn't get the event at all.

One should not do [`$emit`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) on the `$rootScope`, instead use [`$broadcast`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast).

An event can be [broadcasted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast) to the scope children or [emitted](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) to scope parents.

Comment: The problem is that the $emit is in a $rootscope  level, so the $scope didn't get the event at all.

Comment: One should not do `$emit` on the `$rootScope`, use `$broadcast`.